# Using alias for reference to anonymous structure results in error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, using-declaration

My theory is that gcc has a bug. The following compiles in both clang and gcc:

```
using type = const struct {}&;
```

But now when I change it to an rvalue reference it compiles with clang but not with gcc:

```
using type = const struct {}&&;

// main.cpp:8:17: error: expected ';' after struct definition
//  typedef struct {}&& type;
//                  ^
// main.cpp:8:17: error: missing type-name in typedef-declaration
// main.cpp:8:22: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
//  typedef const struct {}&& type;
//                                ^
```

It fails with the `typedef` version as well with the same error:

```
typedef const struct {}&& type;
```

Why does this fail to compile in gcc? Is this an issue with the standard or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a `gcc` bug, the grammar for an *unnamed class* is covered in section `9` *[class]* and we have the following:

```
class-specifier:
    class-head { member-specificationopt}
class-head:
    class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt class-head-name class-virt-specifieropt base-clauseopt
    class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt base-clauseopt
```

and the following text:

> A class-specifier whose class-head omits the class-head-name defines an unnamed class.

so an *unnamed class* is simply a *class-specifier* without a name and *class-specifier* is a *type-specifier* and section `7.1.3` *[dcl.typedef]* says:

> The typedef specifier shall not be combined in a declspecifier-
>   seq with any other kind of specifier except a type-specifier

and does not have any restrictions with respect to *unnamed class* and only refers to them in this paragraph:

> If the typedef declaration defines an unnamed class (or enum), the
>   first typedef-name declared by the declaration to be that class type
>   (or enum type) is used to denote the class type (or enum type) for
>   linkage purposes only (3.5). [ Example:
>
> ```
> typedef struct { } *ps, S; // S is the class name for linkage purposes
> ```
>
> —end example ]